# Which is the right way of recovering from a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scrapping a web site, but sometimes the laptop lost the connection, and I got (obviously) a `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`. Which is the right (or most elegant?) way of recover from this error? I mean: I don't want the program to stop, but retry the connection, maybe some seconds later? This is my code, but I got the feeling is not correct:

```
def make_soup(session,url):
    try:
       n = randint(1, MAX_NAPTIME) 
       sleep(n)
       response = session.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as req_ce:
        error_msg = req_ce.args[0].reason.strerror
        print "Error: %s con la url %s" % (eror_msg, url)
        session = logout(session)
        n = randint(MIN_SLEEPTIME, MAX_SLEEPTIME)
        sleep(n)
        session = login(session)
        response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return soup
```

Any ideas?

Note that I need a session to scrap this pages, so, I think that the `login` (i.e. login again to the site, after a logout) could be cause troubles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So why not something like

```
import requests
import time

def retry(cooloff=5, exc_type=None):
    if not exc_type:
        exc_type = [requests.exceptions.ConnectionError]

    def real_decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            while True:
                try:
                    return function(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    if e.__class__ in exc_type:
                        print "failed (?)"
                        time.sleep(cooloff)
                    else:
                        raise e
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator
```

Which is a decorator that allows you to call any function until it succeeds. e.g.

```
@retry(exc_type=[ZeroDivisionError])
def test():
    return 1/0

print test()
```

Which will just print "failed (y)" every 5 seconds until the end of time (or until the laws of math change)

Answer (score 0):

Is it really needed to logout and relogin into your session? I'd just retry the connection the same way:

```
def make_soup(session,url):
    success = False
    response = None
    for attempt in range(1, MAXTRIES):
        try:
            response = session.get(url)
            # If session.get succeeded, we break out of the
            # for loop after setting a success flag
            success = True
            break
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as req_ce:
            error_msg = req_ce.args[0].reason.strerror
            print "Error: %s con la url %s" % (error_msg, url)
            print " Attempt %s of %s" % (attempt, MAXTRIES)
            sleep(randint(MIN_SLEEPTIME, MAX_SLEEPTIME))

    # Figure out if we were successful. 
    # Note it may not be needed to have a flag, you can maybe just
    # check the value of response here.
    if not success:
        print "Couldn't get it after retrying many times"
        return None

    #Once we get here, we know we got a good response
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return soup
```